# ASP.NET Webforms Error When Trying to Update SQL Data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, webforms

my question is about how to go about updating data in a ASP.NET listview using a stored procedure.

I'm getting an error message whenever I try to update any data in my listview stating that my stored procedure has [too many arguments specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMExE.png).

I've looked through all of my code and all of my arguments seem to match up with my stored procedure so I think it might have to do with how I created the listview (just dragging and dropping it in design view using visual studio 2015) or it's something wrong with my stored procedure.

I've been stuck on this issue for about a day now and I feel like I'm missing something real simple here but can't quite put my finger on it.

If anyone could help my out I would greatly appreciate it. This app I'm working on uses vb.net as it's back-end and used ASP.NET web forms. Below is the code for the page I'm working on.

ASP.NET Page (Might not work properly since it uses a master page and some other external resources)

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/MasterPage.Master" CodeBehind="CodeManagement.aspx.vb" Inherits="OcasNS.CodeManagement" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderInHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH1_DontUseInAContentPageItsJustForTheseJavaScriptFiles" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <p>Course Code:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
    &nbsp;<br />
    <p>Course Title:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
&nbsp;<br />
    <p>Class/Group:<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <p>Career Tech Course Type:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OKECSTestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="spCodeManagementLookup" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="spCodeManagementUpdate" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ClassGroupID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CourseDescription" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ClassSubjectCode" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ClassGroupID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassGroupIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassGroupID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassSubjectCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassSubjectCode") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color:#008A8C;color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassGroupIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassGroupID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ClassSubjectCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClassSubjectCode") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ClassSubjectCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClassSubjectCode") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassGroupIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassGroupID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassSubjectCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassSubjectCode") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                            <tr runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                                <th runat="server"></th>
                                <th runat="server">ClassGroupID</th>
                                <th runat="server">Description</th>
                                <th runat="server">ClassSubjectCode</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" style="text-align: center;background-color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #000000;">
                        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                                <asp:NumericPagerField />
                                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color:#008A8C;font-weight: bold;color: #FFFFFF;">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassGroupIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassGroupID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ClassSubjectCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClassSubjectCode") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />
    &nbsp;<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br /> 

    <button type="button">Save</button>
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button">Export To Excel</button>

</asp:Content>
```

Update Stored Procedure (The one causing the error)

```
@ClassGroupID INT,
@CourseDescription VARCHAR(100),
@ClassSubjectCode VARCHAR(20)

UPDATE [dbo].[tb_oecs_CodeClassGroup]
    SET [Description] = @CourseDescription
    , [ClassSubjectCode] = @ClassSubjectCode
WHERE ClassGroupID = @ClassGroupID
```

Lookup Stored Procedure (This loads the data into the Listview)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    g.ClassGroupID
   ,g.Description
   ,g.ClassSubjectCode
FROM tb_oecs_CodeClassGroup g
JOIN tb_oecs_CodeClass c
    ON g.ClassGroupID = c.ClassGroupID
ORDER BY g.ClassGroupID
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Alright I'll do that real quick. Whenever I was pasting in my sql code it wasn't formatting properly but I'll try it again real quick.

Comment: Could you share the code beside?

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to work with web form pages, and I never used a default list view for anything, so take this with a grain of salt- but your form has four input fields (two text boxes and two drop downs) so I'm thinking that's what's being input to your proc.

Comment: @kblok What do you mean by code beside? Like I said up above I just dragged and dropped the listview onto the page and linked it up with my SQL Data Source. If there is a place where Visual Studio stores this auto generated code I will post it. I just don't have much experience working with web forms at all as this is an older app.

Comment: @wicker95 Right now the text boxes and drop down lists don't do anything so I'm not sure if that would be causing the issue or not.

Comment: Check my answer, I don't know if it's the final answer, but I easy to write there than in a comment

Comment: What is the complete definition of the stored procedure?